# Array transformation in JS

Tags: javascript

I have array transformation required as below in JS.

Source Array

```
var numbers =
[ 
[0,0,4],
[0,1,9],
[0,2,16] ,
[0,2,7] ,
[0,2,5] ,
[1,0,1],
[1,1,2],
[1,1,4],
[1,2,3] 
];
```

Here first value in the source array represents row of target array, second value represents column of target array.

So the expected result array looks like

```
var result = [
[4, 9, [16, 7, 5]],
[1, [2, 4], 3]
];
```

Note: 
1.Source/Target array can contain N number of rows & columns.

Comment: What code have you tried? We are not here to do your homework.

Comment: @Paulpro, appreciate your efforts, but it doesn't handle duplicate, which I didn't mention, But the answers posted here handle it though.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález, well I did try with map function, I'm pretty sure that wouldn't help, so I didn't add it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could reduce the array and check the target element and assign the value or take an array.

```js
var numbers = [[0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 9], [0, 2, 16], [0, 2, 7], [0, 2, 5], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3]],
    result = numbers.reduce((r, [i, j, v]) => {
        r[i] = r[i] || [];
        r[i][j] = r[i][j] === undefined
            ? v
            : [].concat(r[i][j], v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `reduce` method.

```js
var numbers = [[0, 0, 4], [0, 1, 9], [0, 2, 16], [0, 2, 7], [0, 2, 5], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3]];

const result = numbers.reduce((r, [row, col, val]) => {
  if (!r[row]) r[row] = [];

  const el = r[row][col];

  if (el) {
    if (Array.isArray(el)) el.push(val);
    else r[row][col] = [el, val];
  } else {
    r[row][col] = val
  }

  return r;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Well this works for my requirement as well, but couldn't accept both the answers. appreciate your efforts  , thanks:)

Comment: @Ram Kumar  You're welcome.